# Powershell: Check if page has unpublished version?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, publishing-page, versioning

How can I use PowerShell to check if the latest version of a publishing page has been published?

Answer (score -1):

Please run the following PowerShell script:

```
if ((gsnp Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null){
    asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction Stop
}

$site = Get-SPSite http://intranet
$log = "C:\temp\PageLayouts.csv"

##Check if log file exists and clear its content

if ((Test-Path -Path $log -ea SilentlyContinue) -ne $null){
    clc $log
    ac $log "Page URL, Page Title, Page Layout URL, Page Layout Title"
} 

##loop through all webs in the site collection

$site | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | %{
    $web = $_

    ## Get the page library and items

    $pl = $web.Lists["Pages"]
    $pages = $pl.Items
    foreach ($page in $pages){

        ## add content to the log file

        ac $log "$($web.url)/$($page.Url), $($page.Title), $($page.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"])"
    }
}

$site.Dispose()
```

More information, please refer to **[this article](http://blog.riccardocelesti.it/list-all-publishing-pages-and-their-associated-page-layout/)**.

Comment: This shows the page layout but not if the latest version is published or not